# how to convert address to map location in googlemaps with angular?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I have looked at http://angular-google-maps.org/demo . Is there a way to convert an address into a location on the map. I would like to a marker for a location.

Comment: You need to call a geocoding API, like this one from Google... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/